# I'd like to update all the entries of a column of a dataframe so that they are Date type

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("a, b"), datetime=c("2020:12:29 17:20:00","1977:09:18 17:20:00")
```

I'd like for the dataframe to become like this (sorry for my lack of experience):

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("a, b"), datetime=c(2020-12-29, 1977-09-18)`
```

I tried this:

```
for (i in range(nrow(df))) {
  df[i,]$datetime <- as.Date(df[i,]$datetime, format = "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%s")
}
```

Comment: `df$datetime = as.Date(df$datetime, format = "%Y:%m:%d")`  In R, the columns of a dataframe are vectors, so you typically perform an action on all the values of the column at once. https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Comment: Thank you so much :))